# Enable logical replication on Google Cloud Postgres

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, replication, cdc

Is there anyway to enable logical replication `wal_level = logical` on Google Cloud Postgres instance? I want to do CDC (change data capture) to stream WAL Record to Apache Kafka. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not supported by Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 5):

Update:

This feature now is enabled on Google Cloud SQL. To enable `wal_level` to replication you just need to set the flag `cloudsql.logical_decoding` as on.

For more details:

- https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/configure-logical-replication

Note: this issue was solved in [August, 30th release](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/release-notes#August_30_2021).

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud SQL engineering team is working on this issue, [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/120274585) you can find a Feature Request. You can star it in order to get notified when it gets updated. Also you can write a comment there and ask a question. Please, bear in mind that we don't have an ETA for it.

Comment: That issue was created two years ago, and after 70+ starts and 58 comments, it's still a P3 priority. What exactly do you mean by "working on this issue"?